# how to get current location inside a building iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit, core-location

How is it possible to obtain the current location inside a building. I want to develop an application similar to this http://matadornetwork.com/goods/point-inside-indoor-map-application-for-the-iphone-and-android/ (on a smaller/less complicated scale) and wondering on the approach i should take. Are there any tutorials/examples/articles that would point me in the right direction? Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` or `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` you can expect to get a relatively accurate location of your user [see Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1)].  You need to consider that

- Indoor use of the GPS will make precise location difficult
- iPod Touch and iPad users won't be able to get precise location
- I doubt altitude will be precise enough to make the difference between floors in high rises

Also consider you'll have to gather a ton of information on the buildings you want to map (not only draw their floorplan but also get their precise coordinates).

After you have all this information, presenting a glowing dot on an image shouldn't be difficult, just a matter of transforming the geo coordinates into something more manageable (at the scale of the CGRect of the different images representing the buildings).  No need to use mapkit.

As of the software your linking to, I have doubts it can accurately delivers results in term of the current location of users (but still being useful to get phone numbers and compass information for example). Unfortunately though, this kind of technology is very promising.

Answer (score 1):

[Indoor Navigation System for Handheld Devices](http://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-102209-164024/unrestricted/Indoor_Navigation_System_for_Handheld_Devices.pdf) shows up a few possibilities how indoor navigation could work.